# An error occurred while installing twisted

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I'm trying to install scrapy by using `pipenv install scrapy` but when it comes to installing the dependencies. It fails.

```
Installing scrapy…
Adding scrapy to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (ad2c1d)…
  ================================ 25/25 - 00:00:06
An error occurred while installing twisted==19.10.0 ; python_version >= '3.5'
```

I'm running python 3.8 inside a virtual environment. With Pycharm as my IDE.

I originally thought that maybe I was using an older version of Python which was causing a conflict.

My Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
scrapy = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Comment: what happens if you do a `which pipenv` or a `where pipenv` on the command line?

Comment: 'which is not a recognized...' strange.. as I use pip env all the time and haven't had an error.

Comment: Sorry if you are on windows use `where` if you are on linux use `which`.

Comment: ah C:\Users\Kev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pipenv.exe

Answer (score 0):

Installing scrapy via `pip` is tricky because it's dependencies `twisted` and `lxml` require C++ compiler.

There is only one reliable and officially recommended ([docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows)) way to install it on windows - using anaconda distribution (not `pip`